# Can I use Java to click Excel's "save" button after macros run?

Tags: java, excel, vba, aspose

I'm trying to automate a process that's currently manual.

So far, I have an Excel template with macros that does some formatting and then prompts the user to save the PDF with a file name already filled in.  They just have to click the save button.

I also have a Java program that monitors a folder and as soon as the Excel file gets dropped, it opens the file.

What I'm not sure about is, how do I use Java to click Excel's "save" button?

I know Java can save an Excel file as PDF without opening it, but I want the macros to run before it saves.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use VBA to save the file? Is the macro written in vba? Why do you require user input to save?

```
expression.Save
```

> *expression* A variable that represents a Workbook object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.Save